# WPF drop event for empty groupbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Im trying to implement an empty WPF groupbox as a landing zone for drop event (e.g. Files).

But he following xaml

```xml
 <GroupBox Header="Drop Files to convert in here" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="GroupBox_DragEnter" Drop="GroupBox_Drop" />
```

just accepts Drops on it's exactly border - and not as wanted on the whole control (space inside the group box).
How can I accept Drops for the whole control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a common "problem" in WPF,  just set the background property of the empty control and it should work as expected.

Comment: This solution did the job for me. Don't use any transparency - otherwise it won't work.

Comment: From my experience transparency works as well. as long as you set the background property to anything it should work.

Comment: I can't believe this darn "feature" cost one of my beautiful working day morning. And yes `Background="Transparent"` would suffice (at least in .NET Framework 4.8)

Answer (score 0):

The GroupBox is a [HeaderContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548.aspx) meaning it's content can only hold a single item.  If you are wanting to drop multiple files into a GroupBox, I suggest you add a ItemsControl inside of your GroupBox, and when you drop a file add items to that control.

```
<GroupBox Header="Drop Files to convert in here" AllowDrop="true" DragEnter="ItemsControl_DragEnter" Drop="ItemsControl_Drop">
    <ItemsControl  />
</GroupBox>
```

I've made a small sample with xaml very similar to this. This should allow drops for the whole control.

Comment: The amount of dropped Items isn't the problem. It works with an control inside and on its drawn boarder as well. But it doesn't work in the empty space inside the group box. The event seems not to bubble up.

Comment: Can you post more xaml and source code so I can get a clearer idea of the problem?